# A question on the DeTurck trick

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, dg.differential-geometry

I am probably being obtuse here, but there is something in the DeTurck trick that I do not understand precisely. I was reading from Andrews Hopper, and they (on page 91) say that the equation $\frac{\partial g}{\partial t} = Q$ has a solution from the existence of parabolic equations. They have to prove that $Q$ is elliptic first. They are calculating that the linearisation of $Q$ is $DQ (h) = \Delta h + A$, from which the principal symbol is $\hat{\sigma}\[DQ\](\xi)h = |\xi|^2 h$. My question is: is it obvious that the principal symbol of $Q$ is as given above? My suspicion comes from the fact that the $\Delta$ is front of $h$ is still time dependent.

Please forgive me if this is too obvious.

Comment: Both the Laplacian $\Delta=g^{ij}\nabla_i \nabla_j$ and the norm $\lvert \xi \rvert^2=g^{ij}\xi_i\xi_j$ depend on the (inverse) metric and thus on time. What exactly is your suspicion about that?

Comment: In http://maths.anu.edu.au/~andrews/book.pdf, this appears to be on page 77. What's missing here is a reference for "the standard theory of partial differential equations", stating and proving a theorem on short time existence of the solution to the initial value problem for a nonlinear parabolic PDE on a smooth manifold. People in Ricci flow seem to take this theorem for granted, and indeed it is a straightforward consequence of standard estimates and techniques used for solving parabolic PDE's. But I don't know of a reference that does this specifically on manifolds.

Comment: @Deane: Quoting "the standard theory of parabolic PDEs" seems to be a good old tradition :-) I am not aware of a good reference either.

Comment: Robert, that's true. I've been guilty of it myself. But it's become apparent to me recently when discussing such things with either students or mathematicians who are not PDE experts that it's not an acceptable practice. At the very least, there should be a precise statement of what's true. This for example is somewhat easier if the manifold is compact without boundary but gets trickier if the manifold is noncompact or has boundary.

Comment: The heat equation is a bit of a pain to adapt to manifolds, because it has infinite speed of propagation. With a linear hyperbolic equation on a manifold, you really can use a partition of unity and restrict to a co-ordinate chart and cite a theorem from a standard PDE textbook. This just doesn't work for a linear heat equation on a manifold. You really have to verify that the proof that appears in in a standard PDE textbook still works when you are on a manifold instead of a domain in $R^n$.

Comment: I agree with Deane and Robert that "The standard theory of parabolic PDEs" would deserve a modern and readable reference which treats the case of manifolds.

Comment: Okay, if I ever write an exposition about Ricci flow, I will remember your comment...

Comment: For compact manifolds and quasilinear parabolic equations of any order, you can look at this recent paper of Mantegazza-Martinazzi http://cvgmt.sns.it/media/doc/paper/286/quasilin.pdf that does all the details carefully.

Comment: Actually, since you're still young, I recommend that you *don't* act on my views. I recently tried to write out a proof for a linear heat equation on a manifold, and it was sufficiently painful that I have given up for now. I recommend that you focus on working on and writing about new stuff that will advance your career and status as a mathematician. Writing out a careful proof of short time existence of a linear or even nonlinear heat equation on a manifold will earn you nothing (even though many of us will be grateful for it).

Comment: @Deane: Thanks, I know that this doesn't give career credits. In fact, my comment "if I ever write...." contained a big "if" and I don't plan to write a book within the next 10 years or so... Anyway, I think we got somewhat distracted and the original question seems to be just something basic like: "Can the principal symbol of Q depend on time?", "How to compute the symbol of Q?", etc.

Comment: One way to solve the linear heat equation with time-varying metric is to first solve the linear heat equation with time-independent metric (using the essential self-adjointness of the Laplacian, see e.g. http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/the-spectral-theorem-and-its-converses-for-unbounded-symmetric-operators/ ), obtain parabolic estimates for that equation, and then get short-time local existence for the time-varying metric heat equation by a perturbative argument (as discussed for instance in Remark 2 of http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/03/28/285g-lecture-1-ricci-flow/ ).

Comment: @Robert Yes, you are right, I was just a bit uneasy about the principal symbol depending on time, and could not find a decent statement of the existence theorem. I understand how to compute the symbol though. 

@Terry Thanks for your comment. I feel a lot better thinking about it in the way you have suggested. 

@YangMills Thanks for the reference – anonymous 0 secs ago

Answer (score 3):

The operator $g\mapsto-2\operatorname{Ric}$ is not strictly elliptic since by
the diffeomorphism invariance of the Ricci tensor, if $\frac{\partial
}{\partial s}g=\mathcal{L}_{X}g$, then $\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\left(
-2\operatorname{Ric}\right)  =-2\mathcal{L}_{X}\operatorname{Ric}$. I think
DeTurck's trick is the parabolic version of considering the Ricci tensor in
harmonic coordinates (see Hamilton's Formation of Singularities paper). Here
are some related calculations, although not complete nor tied together well.
The linearization of the map $g\mapsto-2\operatorname{Ric}$ is given by: if
$\frac{\partial}{\partial s}g=v$, then
$$
D_{v}\left(  -2\operatorname{Ric}\right)  =\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\left(
-2\operatorname{Ric}\right)  =\Delta v-2\operatorname{Sym}\left(
\operatorname{tr}{}_{1,4}(\nabla^{2}v)\right)  +\nabla^{2}V,
$$
where $V=\operatorname{tr}v$. By commuting covariant derivatives, we may
rewrite this as $\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\left(  -2\operatorname{Ric}
\right)  =\Delta_{L}v-\mathcal{L}_{W}g$, where $W=\operatorname{div}
(v-\frac{V}{2}g)$ and $\Delta_{L}$ is the Lichnerowicz Laplacian. (Digression:
e.g., taking $v=\operatorname{Ric}$, we obtain under Ricci flow that
$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\operatorname{Ric}=D_{-2v}\left(
\operatorname{Ric}\right)  =D_{v}\left(  -2\operatorname{Ric}\right)
=\Delta_{L}\operatorname{Ric}$ since $W=0$ by the contracted second Bianchi identity.)

The variation of the Levi-Civita connection $\nabla:\Gamma(TM)\times
\Gamma(TM)\rightarrow\Gamma(TM)$ is the tensor (use $g$ to identify $TM$ and
$T^{\ast}M$)
$$
(\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\nabla)(X,Y,Z)=\frac{1}{2}(\nabla_{X}
v(Y,Z)+\nabla_{Y}v(X,Z)-\nabla_{Z}v(X,Y)),
$$
so that $\operatorname{tr}{}_{1,2}(\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\nabla
)=\operatorname{div}v-\frac{1}{2}\nabla V=W$. Since $\Delta=\operatorname{tr}
_{g}\nabla^{2}$, we have $\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\Delta=-v\cdot\nabla
^{2}-\mathcal{L}_{W}$, where the highest order term in $v$ on the right side
is $-\mathcal{L}_{W}$. The same is essentially true for the map Laplacian if
we linearize with respect to the domain metric.

Fix a connection $\tilde{\nabla}$ and define $U=\operatorname{tr}{}
_{1,2}(\nabla-\tilde{\nabla})$. The Ricci-DeTurck flow is $\frac{\partial
}{\partial t}g=-2\operatorname{Ric}+\mathcal{L}_{U}g\doteqdot Q(g)$. We have
$\frac{\partial U}{\partial s}=W$ up to lower (zeroth) order terms in $v$. So
$\frac{\partial}{\partial s}Q(g)=\Delta v+P\left(  v\right)  $, where $P$ is
lower order in $v$. Replacing $\nabla_{i}$ by $\xi_{i}$ in $\Delta
=g^{ij}\nabla_{i}\nabla_{j}$, we obtain the symbol $\left\vert \xi\right\vert
^{2}$ for $\xi\in T^{\ast}M$ as Robert Haslhofer wrote.